# resultados de regresión en stargazer en r

Tags: r, rstudio

Despues de hacer una regresion lineal, quisiera que el resultado lo imprima en un cuadro con la libreria stargazer con el type="html", pero la consola imprime un conjunto de codigos html en lugar de la tabla.
Esto es algo de lo que hice:

```
cpbi_ts= ts(cpbi,
            start = 1988,
            end = 2018      )

tc_ts=ts(VITRM,
         start = 1988,
         end = 2018       )

data_1= ts.union(cpbi_ts,tc_ts)

m1=lm(cpbi_ts~tc_ts,
         start = 1998,
         end = 2018)

stargazer(m1,type="html",align = FALSE, no.space=FALSE)
```

cuando se ejecuta la ultima linea de codigo, el resultado debería ser una tabla pero la consola imprime:

```
<table style="text-align:center"><tr><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td><em>Dependent variable:</em></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td colspan="1" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>cpbi_ts</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">tc_ts</td><td>-0.094<sup>**</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(0.035)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Constant</td><td>0.024<sup>**</sup></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>(0.011)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Observations</td><td>21</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">R<sup>2</sup></td><td>0.280</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Adjusted R<sup>2</sup></td><td>0.240</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">Residual Std. Error</td><td>0.051 (df = 19)</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">F Statistic</td><td>7.400<sup>**</sup> (df = 1; 19)</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"><em>Note:</em></td><td style="text-align:right"><sup>*</sup>p<0.1; <sup>**</sup>p<0.05; <sup>***</sup>p<0.01</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer necesitas agregar el argumento `out` a la función `stargazer`

```
x<-1:30
y<-2+3*x+rnorm(30)

m1<-lm(y~x)
class(m1)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1,type="html",align = FALSE, no.space=FALSE, out="m1.html")
```

Luego puedes abrir el archivo desde tu directorio de trabajo y podrás ver la tabla, en mi caso esto es lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Luego ir a files y esta el archivo en html para abrir.

Answer (score 1):

`stargazer` es un paquete pensado para integrar con `Rmarkdown`, es decir escribir código R con código Markdown, por ejemplo, algo como esto en el marco de un documento `Rmd`:

````
## `stargazer` con Rmarkdown

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(stargazer)
# Ejemplo de la ayuda de Lm()
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
m1 <- lm(weight ~ group)
stargazer(m1, header=FALSE, type='html')
```
````

Al presionar el botón de `knitr` generaría algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto puede visualizarse directamente en el panel del "Viewer" de **Rstudio** o en una ventana independiente (además de poder exportarse a Word o Pdf). Aclaración: a efectos de reproducir el ejemplo, habría que pegar el código en un nuevo documento RMarkdown.

Ahora bien, si lo que buscas es usar `stargazer()` dentro de un script común de R, lo único que verás es el código necesario para "dibujar" la tabla (eventualmente, texto, html o latex). Puedes, si, claro, usar la opción de salida `type="text"`, para generar algo así:

```
stargazer(m1,type="text",align = FALSE, no.space=FALSE)
```

La salida en consola sería algo así:

```
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                              weight           
-----------------------------------------------
groupTrt                      -0.371           
                              (0.311)          

Constant                     5.032***          
                              (0.220)          

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    20             
R2                             0.073           
Adjusted R2                    0.022           
Residual Std. Error       0.696 (df = 18)      
F Statistic             1.419 (df = 1; 18)     
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Otra forma, de la que ya tienes una respuesta, sería, salvar la salida como un `html` completo y verlo con el navegador. Sino, hay una practica forma de automatizar esto mismo. [Aquí la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871109/6836377), lo único que hice fue modificar el nombre de la función:

```
print.htmlcode<- function(x, useViewer = TRUE, ...){
    # Don't use viewer if in knitr
    if (useViewer &&
        !"package:knitr" %in% search()){
        htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext=".html")
        htmlPage <- paste("<html>",
                          "<head>",
                          "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">",
                          "</head>",
                          "<body>",
                          "<div style=\"margin: 0 auto; display: table; margin-top: 1em;\">",
                          x,
                          "</div>",
                          "</body>",
                          "</html>", sep="\n")
        cat(htmlPage, file=htmlFile)

        viewer <- getOption("viewer")
        if (!is.null(viewer) &&
            is.function(viewer)){
            # (code to write some content to the file)
            viewer(htmlFile)
        }else{
            utils::browseURL(htmlFile)
        }
    }else{
        cat(x)
    }
}
```

Entonces puedes hacer:

```
print_htmlcode(stargazer(m1,type="html",align = FALSE, no.space=FALSE))
```